# #PHP-PKPass IOS 15.5 Expiry Date Problem occurring in 24 hours not 1 year

Tags: ios, date

Have been using PHP-PKPass successfully for a few years creating membership passes that expire 1 year in the future.

Just with the release of IOS 15.5 the certificate passes seem to be expiring 24 hours after they are installed to the Apple device, on older IOS it is still fine...

No useful suggestions on Apple forum at present (e.g.  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708761), has anyone got a workaround or is it just an IOS bug that has been introduced...?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug, because in the archive of the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/TopLevel.html) it says that the expirationDate field is the one that determines whether the pass shows as expired or not in the wallet :

> A pass is marked as expired if the current date is after the pass’s expiration date, or if the pass has been explicitly marked as voided.

While relevantDate description says :

> Recommended for event tickets and boarding passes; otherwise optional. Date and time when the pass becomes relevant. For example, the start time of a movie.
> The value must be a complete date with hours and minutes, and may optionally include seconds.

However, in iOS 15 is seems that the pass is actually expired when we have a relevantDate set in the past.